# Light up a single LED five (5) times in a row for one (1) second on and off, and then five times in a row for half (1 2 ) of a second

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I don't know how to off all led circuit for temporary. I need to light up a single LED five (5) times in a row for one (1) second on and off, and then five times in a row for half (1/2) of a second.

Could u show the code how to write code for this program?

```
int pin[]={13,12,9,6};
int x=4;

void setup()
{
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    pinMode(pin[i],OUTPUT);
  } 
}

void loop()
{
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
    for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
      digitalWrite(pin[i], HIGH);
      delay(200); // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s)
      digitalWrite(pin[i], LOW);
      delay(200); // Wait for 1000 millisecond(s) 
    }
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean round;
int pin[]={13,12,9,6};
int i;

void setup() {
  round =1;
  i=0;
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    pinMode(pin[j],OUTPUT);
  } 

}

void loop() {
  if(round<6){
    digitalWrite(pin[i],HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(pin[i],LOW);
    round++;
  }

  else{
    digitalWrite(pin[i],HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(pin[i],LOW);
    round++;
    if(round >10){
      round=0;
      i++;
      if(i>3) i=0;
    }
  }

}
```